# Django: how to fetch records only that matches the region belongs to login user?

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization

**Data:**

1. Transaction table with region field (Oracle database-Only read access).
2. Users table in excel with region field. (I can add this table in secondary database)

**LDAP Authentication** is used.

Using views(**raw SQL query** is used), I am showing aggregated data of transaction table.

All users are seeing same data, as there is no filter on the region.

Now, I want to aggregate only those records which login user's region belongs to.

How can these implemented?

**My approach:**

- Create region model
- Implement a Foreign Key with transaction tables(Is it possible?)

What is best approach to this scenario?

Please explain clearly in steps.

**NOTE:** I have solved my problem. Please look my answer. Is there any drawbacks of my approach? (New best approach is appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to achieve fine grained relationship-based access control on the data in your database. You should not implement this in your code but rather delegate it to an authorization layer.

Relational database vendors have different ways of dealing with this such as FGAC. The field as a whole is known as dynamic data masking. I work for company that delivers a policy-based proxy that will effectively filter out and mask your data so that you only see The data that belongs to the region that user belongs to. It's called [Axiomatics Data Access Filter](https://www.axiomatics.com/product/axiomatics-data-access-filter-adaf/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to implement this in my scenario? Can you please elaborate clearly like where is excel users table is used, how it going to link with database and filter my data. Please make your approach in steps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following below steps.

**Steps:**

1. Created a DataFrame of User Table present in excel using Pandas in my views.py.
2. Captured a login user ID into a variable.
3. Filtered this User ID in DataFrame and got his/her region and then I have passed this variable to final aggregating query and filtered there.

Short and simple.